# a way to check current field history data retention

Tags: metadata-api, history-tracking

The Data Retention Policy for Field History states that the default values are : 18 months of production storage and 0 years of archive storage. However this value can be changed either by metadata API or direct request to Salesforce (depending on org version).

Now, is there a way to check if the default values have been overridden, assuming that there is nothing about that in metadata file?

Comment: One way is to make some changes and wait 18 moths but my client wouldn't like this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading, I don't think there is any way to know if the default values are still configured or if they have been overridden.  You will just have to compare the metadata files to the known default values

- 18 months archived
- 10 years deleted. (I think you meant to type 10, no 0)

Comment: This [document](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/field_history_retention.pdf) says it's 0, but indeed it seems like a typo.

Comment: Check out page five under the "archiveRetentionYears". Looks like an inconsistency from the beginning of the file.